# How to cache FutureBuilder async results with screen navigation when using BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter

I am using `BottomNavigationBar` to display a list of three menus. When user selects the `Gallery` I render a `Stateful` component that renders `FutureBuilder` in its `build` method. This works as expected, with the exception that when user navigates to another screen, `Gallery` widget is disposed off and thus I lose all of the images I just fetched. How do I cache them effectively?

`home-page.dart` widget:

```
final List<Widget> _menuOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Schedules',
      style: optionStyle
    ),
    Text(
      'Stats',
      style: optionStyle
    ),    
    GalleryPage(key: PageStorageKey('gallery'))
  ];

void _onMenuSelected(int index){
    setState(() {      
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    //...
    body: Center(
      child: _menuOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.schedule),
          title: Text('Schedules'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.satellite),
          title: Text('Stats'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.image),
          title: Text('Gallery'),          
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      onTap: _onMenuSelected,
    )
```

`gallery-page.dart` widget:

```
class GalleryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  GalleryPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GalleryPageState createState() => _GalleryPageState();
}

class _GalleryPageState extends State<GalleryPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  Future<List<GalleryImage>> futureGalleryImages;
  final AsyncMemoizer _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    // TODO: implement deactivate
    super.deactivate();    
    print('deactiveating');
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _populateGalleryImages();
  }



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: this.futureGalleryImages,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
         //...
         return _createListView(context, snapshot);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future _populateGalleryImages() {    
    return this._memoizer.runOnce(() async {
      this.futureGalleryImages = GalleryService().fetchGalleryImages();
    });
  }
```

Things I have tried:

1. Using the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` mixin with the `wantKeepAlive` property set to true. This however doesn't work as my component always enters the `deactive` life cycle and is always disposed. The data fetching occurs every time. I was hoping to use `AsyncMemoizer` if the component did not get disposed.
2. Using `PageStorageKey` when instantiating the component as seen above. Did not work.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?